# Obter Json de consulta feito no google com WebBrowser C#

Tags: c#, json, navegador-de-internet

Preciso realizar o seguinte processo, realizar uma busca no google e obter as informações da pesquisa em formato Json, como poderia fazer isso?

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira, usei o WebBrowser do C# e naveguei no site www.google.com.br, até ai deu certo, só que preciso pegar essas informações como Título e Link dos resultado desta pesquisa, alguém sabe qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

OBS: Não posso usar a API do google, preciso fazer na mão.

[image: WebBrowser]

```
    private void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate("www.google.com.br/search?q=" + txtPesquisa.Text);

        var document = webBrowser.Document;
    }
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar a [API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction) do Google para isso.

Comment: Veja se te ajuda a minha resposta

Comment: A API do google existe uma limitação de quantas requisições fazer, depois disso é pago.. Gostei da resposta do @RovannLinhalis hahah +1.

Comment: hehe obrigado =]

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, sua resposta me ajudou sim, agora estou implementando ela. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, só me tira uma dúvida amigo, como você sabe essas tags de resultado do google? pois no Document que o WebBrowser carrega não consigo ver essas tags lá, existe alguma documentação pra isso?

Comment: não... abre a pesquisa pelo google chrome, e em cima de um dos resultados clique com o botão direito, e depois em inspecionar, o chrome vai abrir o html da página naquele elemento, depois é só analisar e entender o html mesmo

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, Perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, estou tendo um problema, vê se consegue me ajudar, quando fiz o teste com seu código, ele funcionou perfeitamente quando eu arrasto o componente WebBrowser para meu formulário. Quando consegui fazer funcionar eu passei todo esse código para uma DLL, onde vou fazer uma API para esse processo, ou seja, iria passar a string da pesquisa e executar tudo dentro da DLL e depois obter o objeto Json do resultado, mas o problema é o seguinte, quando uso o WebBrowser criado no código o resultado da pesquisa fica vazia. Sabe porque?

Comment: teria q ver seu código, mais imagino que seja pelo evento `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` que pode não estar sendo disparado

Comment: Como faço para postar meu código, mostro por aqui mesmo?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, creio que não seja nada relacionado a evento, pois em testes eu apenas coloquei o componente WebBrowser coloquei a Url com www.google.com.br e depois coloquei o _WebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com.br/search?q=" + textoConsulta); e trouxe o resultado correto. E Agora eu criei o WebBrowser como uma propriedade e configurei ele assim: _WebBrowser.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com.br", UriKind.Absolute);
            _WebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com.br/search?q=" + textoConsulta); , desse jeito ele não me retorna nada.

Comment: tenta me passar o código pra eu ver

Comment: Como faço para lhe enviar o meu código ? ele não cabe aqui, e editar o post estragaria o post, não?

Comment: acho q podemos ir no chat

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62208/discussion-between-rovann-linhalis-and-nicola-bogar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos sabemos que o resultado do webBrowser será um Html, sendo assim, vamos percorrer o html obtendo os elementos que são necessários, as divs, no caso do google, que possuem a class 'g' indicando que é um resultado da pesquisa.

Após ter esse elemento, basta pegar o link, indicado pela tag  e então podemos obter suas propriedades.

Segue código:

```
Click:
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com.br/search?num=100&q=carros");
```

> Dica: Utilize o parâmetro num para ter mais resultados: *search?**num=100**&q=[sua pesquisa]*

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection divs = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        List<Resultados> resultados = new List<Resultados>();
        Resultados r;
        foreach (HtmlElement x in divs)
        {
            if (x.GetAttribute("className") == "g")
            {
                HtmlElement link = x.GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                r = new Resultados();
                r.Titulo = link.InnerText;
                r.Url = link.GetAttribute("href");
                resultados.Add(r);
            } 
        }

        int cout = resultados.Count; //Sua List com todos os resultados da pesquisa.

    }

    public class Resultados
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
    }
```

Agora o json: Utilizei a biblioteca `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
string json = "";
foreach (Resultado r in resultados)
    json+=  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);


string seuJsonCompleto = json;
```